# Need help in integrating array list into Flutter GridView

Tags: flutter, arraylist, gridview

I used to use RecyclerView in AS but I have recently started learning Flutter.

I've been searching around and I can't seem to find a cohesive document/reference/example to allow an array List to appear in GridView.

```
List<Test> fbToJson(gdata) {
  var tojson = json.decode(gdata).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return tojson.map<Test>((json) => Test.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class Test {
  String imageUrl;
  String name;

  Test({this.imageUrl,this.name});

  factory Test.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
     return Test(
     imageUrl: json['imageUrl'] as String,
     name:  json['name'] as String
  );
}
}
```

I was already able to pass the above list array to another activity class via Navigator.

My confusion is since this is a list array, I need to iterate through it to show the listed values eg.

```
for(var i in fbdata){
  var myname = i.name;
}
```

I can't find any doc/resource to help show how to integrate this to a gridview if I wish to show both name and urlimage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GridView.builder`

```
      GridView.builder(
        itemCount: fbdata.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10),
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(fbdata[index].name),
              Text(fbdata[index].imageUrl),
            ],
          );
        })
```